# Strange Background For Labels In UITableViewCell

Tags: ios

I am making an app which shows sport results and color codes them accordingly by setting their cell's background color:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (cell == nil)
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (_tabBar.selectedItem == _homeGamesItem) {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"";
        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Home Game %d", indexPath.row];
    } else if (_tabBar.selectedItem == _myEventsItem) {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"";
        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"My Result %d", indexPath.row];
    } else if (_tabBar.selectedItem == _resultsItem) {
        SportEvent *event = [self.appDelegate.user.resultSportEvents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        if ([event.gender isEqualToString:@""]) {
            cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", event.level, event.activity];
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = event.result;
        } else {
            cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@", event.gender, event.level, event.activity];
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = event.result;
        }
        if ([[event.result substringToIndex:1] isEqualToString:@"W"])
            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:1 blue:0 alpha:.05];
        else if ([[event.result substringToIndex:1] isEqualToString:@"T"])
            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:0 alpha:.05];
        else if ([[event.result substringToIndex:1] isEqualToString:@"L"])
            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:0 blue:0 alpha:.05];
    }

    if (_grayedOut) {
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    } else {
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

The strange thing is that this causes some cells to have strange backgrounds right around the labels (my apologies for the massive image):

[image]

Why do only some cells get this strange darkening around the labels?

Comment: Possibly you show more than one label at once and the added alpha shows as a different color

Comment: @gWiz Thanks for your response, but I am using Value1 for the cells, which should not show more than one on top of another. Also I don't think that would mess with the background color. And also why would that only happen to some?

Comment: Could you post more code? (the whole `...cellForRow...` for example?

Comment: @gWiz Thats the entire cellForRow code. Most is probably irrelevant. Tell me if you want any more. Also just in case it helps the cells which this occurs on are always the first 5 (when first launched). I have a feeling it has to do with the fact that 5 of the cells were already shown before going to the results tab, but I don't know why.

Comment: What do you mean the first 5? From the screenshot I see the problem at cells 3, 4, 6 and 10 (assuming the first cell is cell 0).

Comment: @gWiz This is due to the reusability of the cells. I will change the picture to show what I mean. I believe this points to the fact that homeGameCells show first (5 total). I do not know why showing them first would cause this problem though.

Answer (score 0):

Since you use these cells in other tabs, and you only change some cell's background color to white (e.g. homeGames), then add the following code to make all reusable cells have the same color (clearColor) before actually using them again:

```
...
if (cell == nil)
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

//Add This Code
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
//Also make labels same color just to be sure
cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; //or whiteColor
cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; //or whiteColor

if (_tabBar.selectedItem == _homeGamesItem) {
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that makes every row have that problem :(

Comment: Same thing for white.

Comment: I would also try: `tableView.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];` and (if you didn't try): `cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];`

Comment: All rows still have the problem.

Comment: Although this is not a proper solution, you could use another cellIdentifier for the results, so you don't get any cells used in any other tabs

Comment: That worked, but if you figure one out please post a proper answer.